# Should I use Heroku git for source control in addition to production code?

Tags: heroku, gruntjs

I have created one application using NodeJS, Angular and Express which I want to run at Heroku. Now, Im using Grunt to build the code that are placed in the *dist* folder and is ready to be deployed and run on Heroku. This would be done by pushing the *dist* folder in the Heroku git repo.

1. Now, should i push my source code in Heroku git as well?
2. If so, how should I seperate it from dist-folder repository? For instance, I dont want Heroku to run npm install each time i push changes to remote repo. And dist folder should not be part of the source code folder in the repository since it is auto generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a git repository is the only way to push changes to heroku. So yes it is mandatory. Having said that here is what [they](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app) have to say about it.

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as GitHub and treat that as canonical.

Again there is no way to stop them from doing an npm install on each push. Here is a quote from their [getting started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#declare-dependencies-with-npm) guide

> Heroku recognizes an app as Node.js by the existence of a package.json. Even if your app has no dependencies, you should still create a package.json that declares a name, version, and empty dependencies in order that it appear as a Node app.

But I suppose that you could download all the dependencies of your app locally, not specify in `package.json`, push it along with rest of your application and you might trick heroku into thinking that there are no dependencies. Have not tried it myself though.

If you don't want dist folder to be a part of push simply `gitignore` it.

Comment: Thanks! Actually first paragraph in your answer is what I have been wondering.